# error Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header

Tags: ruby, rails, postgresql, pg

Trying to set up postgres for rails.

`bundle install` gives:

```
 Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This resolved my issue:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: I'm glade that you find the solution. Don't forget to [mark your answer as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1137/62483). That is how the site work. Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  I have to wait TWO days before accepting.  That is also a site restriction, at least for my rep :)

Comment: I see, np buddy :)